# In vue.js, an error about computed property

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and try to use computed property but I got the error

**this will cause an error**

```
export default {
    name: 'echarts_demo',
    data() {
      return {
        data:[],
        raw_data:[]
      }
    },
    computed:{
      deal_Data:
        this.do_data

    },
    methods:{
      do_data: function (){
       .....
        }
      },
    },
}
```

if I change it to , it can work well

```
 computed:{
  deal_Data:function(){
    this.do_data()
  }
},
methods:{
  do_data: function (){
     ...
  },
},
```

so what is the reason?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like Vue supports passing a method definition.  My question would be why would you need the method definition?  Just put that code in the computed section.

Comment: There's no reason vue can't do that, it's just javascript. The problem is `this` isn't the right context.

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties must return a value. Do this instead `deal_Data() { return this.do_data()}` in the computed property. The downside to this approach is that the computed property will never update.

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.[Computed Properties - Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)